# Elasticsearch: Undefined method 'perform' for #<Indexer...> [test env]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, elasticsearch

I'm writing tests for my app (in Rspec) and lost a whole day trying to figure out where did I make a mistake with Capybara. I noticed that when a action is called (change_status), the following errors occur in the test.log:

```
undefined method `perform' for #<Indexer:0x000000095d9680>
```

and the changes are not saving. I have no idea where to start looking. I'm guessing it's a problem with Elasticsearch. Here's the whole action from the controller:

```
def change_status
  product = Product.find_by(id: params[:id])
  product.update_attribute(:status, params[:product][:status])
  if params[:product][:status] == "accepted"
    kind = Kind.where(name: "title").first
    product.author.change_points({points: 2, kind: kind.id})
  elsif params[:product][:status] == "rejected"
    kind = Kind.where(name: "title").first
    product.author.change_points({points: 1, kind: kind.id})
    product.author.change_points({points: -3, kind: kind.id})
  end

  user_id = product.author_id
  products = Product.where(author_id: user_id)
  if products.where(status: "accepted").count == 3
    user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    user.update_attribute(:approved, true)
    kind = Kind.where(name: "title").first
    user.change_points({points: 1, kind: kind.id})
    redirect_to products_path
  else
    redirect_to action: "pending_products", id: user_id
  end
end
```

Any suggestion? Besides this, the log is useless...

EDIT:

```
class Indexer
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options queue: 'elasticsearch', retry: false, backtrace: true

  Logger = Sidekiq.logger.level == Logger::DEBUG ? Sidekiq.logger : nil
  Client = Elasticsearch::Client.new host: (ENV['ELASTICSEARCH_URL'] || 'http://localhost:9200'), logger: Logger

  def perform(operation, klass, record_id, options={})
    logger.debug [operation, "#{klass}##{record_id} #{options.inspect}"]

    case operation.to_s
      when /index|update/
        record = klass.constantize.find(record_id)
        record.__elasticsearch__.client = Client
        record.__elasticsearch__.__send__ "#{operation}_document"
      when /delete/
        Client.delete index: klass.constantize.index_name, type: klass.constantize.document_type, id: record_id
      else raise ArgumentError, "Unknown operation '#{operation}'"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If you are missing #perform it hints at some background job doing reindexing. Resque? Sidekiq? Somewhere in your code (probably a sweeper) is a call to Indexer#perform after code change.

Comment: @MilanVladimirovic Just checked Sidekiq. No. I'm going through the code again. BTW, everything's fine in development env. Pozdrav [iz PG] ;)

Comment: Check the elasticsearch-model readme on asynchronous callbacks: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model

Comment: There is an example of a Indexer class with a #perform method and example perform_async callbacks. Check if this applies to your project. Perform missing still points at a class not being prepared to run in a background job. And it's either called directly via perform or indirectly via perform_async through sidekiq worker.

Comment: The difference between dev and test can be caused by a setting for sidekiq in a spec_helper to inline tests. In dev mode the indexer would be placed in a queue and be executed there and you probably wouldnt notice the missing perform method and resulting exceptions and in test mode you would because it would be executed directly.

Comment: On update, destroy and create actions, I call Indexer.perform_async(:update, self.class.to_s, self.id). I include 'sidekiq/testing/inline' in the spec_helper. But, it's still difficult to trace the problem.

Comment: Do you have an Indexer class and does it contain a #perform instance method?